# Create 1 imageView with 9 image Files

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview

I searched from a way to create a single imageView from 9 image files like this :

IMG1 - IMG2 - IMG3

IMG4 - IMG5 - IMG6

IMG7 - IMG8 - IMG9

I seen several interesting topics that helps me. One of these talks about a solution that may fits my needs. In this topic, Dimitar Dimitrov propose this :

> You can try to do it with the raw data, by extracting the pixel data
>   from the images as 32-bit int ARGB pixel arrays, merge in one big
>   array, and create a new Bitmap, using the methods of the Bitmap class
>   like copyPixelsToBuffer(), createBitmap() and setPixels().
>   source : [Render Two images in ImageView in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329720/render-two-images-in-imageview-in-android?answertab=active#tab-top)

So i may extract the 32-bits ARGB pixels from each image file and then create a Bitmap in which i could use the setPixels function to fill in. The problem is that **i don't know how i can "extract the 32-bits ARGB pixels from each image file"** ...

I also saw things about canvas and surfaceView but i never uses them. Furthermore the final object will only be sometimes pinched zoomed (when the user wants it), so i think it'll be easier for me to make it works using a single imageView ...

So i began with this portion of code inside an AsyncTask (to avoid using the UI Thread)
but i already get an OUT OF MEMORY Exception

```
...
@Override
protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {
     return this.createBigBitmap();
}

public Bitmap createBigBitmap() {

Bitmap pageBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(800, 1066, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); // OUT OF MEMORY EXCEPTION

// create an ArrayList of the 9 page Parts
ArrayList<Bitmap> pageParts = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
for(int pagePartNum = 1; pagePartNum <= 9; pagePartNum++){
    Bitmap pagePartBitmap = getPagePart(pageNum, pagePartNum);
    pageParts.add(pagePartBitmap);
}


// try to copy the content of the 9 bitmaps into a single one bitmap
int[] pixels = null;
            int offsetX = 0, offsetY = 0, pagePartNum = 0;

            for (int x = 0; x < this.nbPageRows; x++) {
                for (int y = 0; y < this.nbPageColumns; y++) {
                    pagePartNum = x * this.nbPageColumns + y;
                    Bitmap pagePartBitmap = pageParts.get(pagePartNum);
                    // read pixels from the pagePartBitmap
                    pixels = new int[pagePartBitmap.getHeight() * pagePartBitmap.getWidth()];
                    pagePartBitmap.getPixels(pixels, 0, pagePartBitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0, pagePartBitmap.getWidth(), pagePartBitmap.getHeight());

                    // compute offsetY
                    if(x == 0)
                        offsetY = 0;
                    if(x == 1)
                        offsetY = pageParts.get(0).getHeight();
                    if(x == 2)
                        offsetY = pageParts.get(0).getHeight() * 2;

                    // compute offsetX
                    if(y == 0)
                        offsetX = 0;
                    if(y == 1)
                        offsetX = pageParts.get(0).getWidth();
                    if(y == 2)
                        offsetX = pageParts.get(0).getWidth() * 2;


                    // write pixels read to the pageBitmap
                    pageBitmap.setPixels(pixels, 0, pagePartBitmap.getWidth(), offsetX, offsetY, pagePartBitmap.getWidth(), pagePartBitmap.getHeight());
                    offsetX += pagePartBitmap.getWidth();
                    offsetY += pagePartBitmap.getHeight();

                }
            }
return pageBitmap;
}

// get a bitmap from one of the 9 existing image file page part
private Bitmap getPagePart(int pageNum, int pagePartNum) {
        String imgFilename = this.directory.getAbsolutePath()
                + File.separator + "z-"
                + String.format("%04d", pageNum)
                + "-" + pagePartNum + ".jpg";
        // ajoute le bitmap de la partie de page
        BitmapFactory.Options opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        opt.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFilename, opt);
    }
```

Thank you very much

Comment: I apologize as this sample code seems to work in fact the error is outside of this portion of code.

Answer (score 0):

Read [BitmapRegionDecoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapRegionDecoder.html) and [this](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Gallery2/+/c2c0b01fbbf243eee1a11c33ba6dd1ce918a9ce5/src/com/android/gallery3d/ui/TileImageViewAdapter.java)

**Edit**

Look at [Efficient Bitmap Handling](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) in android to come out from OOM error.
Use following code to decode your bitmap.

```
public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId,
int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = 4;

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
}
```

Comment: Hi Chintan ! I don't understand the whole code of the sample but i guess BitmapRegionDecoder permits to decode a portion of a Bitmap. In my case it's the reverse operation, i take the whole part of the image files to make a single big one