# Multi-user thumbnail in android

Tags: android, thumbnails

I need to show a thumbnail of multiple users like in gmail does when there is multiple people in a thread.

The sample is as follows: [image: image with multiple user thumbnail]

*I'm looking at creating the first image in the listview.*

Image Source: Gmail screenshot in Play store.

Comment: Did you solve the problem? I'm now looking for a good way to achieve it.

Comment: @pedroteran, no I haven't got any leads on it, I kinda dropped this idea for now until it's absolutely necessary.

Comment: thanks for answering! I'll search or evaluate time for doing my own implementation.

Comment: @PedroTeran, I have found a library that can do (sort-of) this [here](https://github.com/amulyakhare/TextDrawable)

Comment: thanks  for posting the library I'm reviewing it, for now I created an textToImage Method to use when users don't have userPicture and  fractioned  the image acoording to the number of participants, but isn't smooth on large listViews  for now,  this post was very helpfull  thanks for sharing it!

Comment: @PedroTeran can you share your function as a gist or something?

Answer (score 1):

Wonder if this may help :

[Render Two images in ImageView in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329720/render-two-images-in-imageview-in-android)

http://androidattop.blogspot.in/2012/06/merge-multiple-images-into-one-image-in.html

Not sure if they can be really helpful, but something close to what your trying to achieve. You could probably even create a custom ImageView and use it instead of the standard ImageView

Comment: Dunno, looks like an older thread. I was thinking that someone would've come up an library by now.